# Why security proof uses random oracles in identity-based encryption?

Tags: identity-based-encryption, random-oracle-model

In identity-based encryption, users decrypt the ciphertext by using private keys.
 Without private key, no one will be able to decrypt.
In security proofs [like here](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-540-30580-4_26#page-1), random oracles are used with the restriction that the attacker is not allowed for key extraction for target identities.
With this restriction, it is sure for security because attacker does not know the private key of target identities.
 Then, why presents random oracles?

Comment: Are you talking about the random oracle model? Or about the Decisional-Diffie-Hellman oracle?

Comment: @CodesInChaos.random oracle model.

Comment: Could you point to the specific security proof you are talking about?

Comment: @otus.Efficient Multi-Receiver Identity-Based Encryption and Its Application to Broadcast Encryption by J.Baek,R. Safavi-Naini, W.Susilo.

Comment: @otus.Authenticated identity-based encryption by Ben. Lynn

Comment: Seems the random oracle model is mentioned in the paper.Just glancing at it (I hope I did not miss anything) it seems to be used as a formal part of the proof, that the encryption is indistinguishable from the random output and that the attacker has no better means that exhaustive search to find a key.

Comment: Gabriel's answer is effectively correct. There are standard-model IBE schemes that achieve the same level of security as random-oracle-based IBEs; however, they typically require a more complicated (and thus, more costly) construction, computing a higher-degree function explicitly, in order to guarantee the same level of 'independence' between different identities' keys/CTs as the RO gives automatically.